# Split hdmi signal the passive way

Tags: connector, impedance-matching, signal-integrity, hdmi

I would like to know if it's possible to split a HDMI signal (generate by raspberry pi or equivalent) to a deserializer (TFP401APZP) and to a micro HDMI.

I have a source going direct to the TFP and I want to add a extra micro HDMI to have ability to export this signal to outside. Because it is embedded product I don't want to deal with an active HDMI signal splitter.

Every TMDS signal pair have impedance matching, length matching from source connector to the TFP and from those track to the extra connector. Length matching is for each diff pair and for group.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to make a wideband power splitter with matched input and output impedances, but the signal level is reduced by half, which greatly limits the length of cable that you'll be able to drive. Also, the physical layout is very critical for flat frequency response.

There's more information [here](https://www.markimicrowave.com/blog/how-to-make-an-n-way-power-splitter/), but the basic idea is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVDFTK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: siiiimultaneous :) signal level being signal power in your answer, I reckon, if you could build the perfect lossless splitter.

Comment: TMDS lines are 100 ohm differential, but they need 50 ohm single-ended termination to 3.3V for proper common mode voltage range.

Comment: @Justme: Note that the two delta-connected resistor networks are independent of each other, and have no effect on the common-mode voltage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: No, signal level is voltage, which is cut in half. Each load gets 1/4 the power (-6 dB), and the rest is lost in the divider itself. A passive splitter can be either low-loss or it can be broadband, but it can't be both. For that, you need an active splitter.

Comment: @DaveTweed It is worth noting that even if it works, you can't pass the official compliance tests with that kind of splitter. And I am a bit worried what happens if one of the displays is turned off, the other display would try to backfeed 3.3V termination to an unpowered display.

Comment: Very interesting documentation. I'll check that ! 
In fact if it's working between source signal to the TFP it's ok for me. The HDMI out is an "option". Event if this need a active signal repeater outside it's still ok for me. In fact I just want to preserve the Source to TFP part.

Answer (score 2):

Justme's answer is sufficient: There's pins that logically can't be split passively. And no, they are not optional; especially working E-DDC is a mandatory requirement for HDMI.

Other than that: The signal lines aren't just "cables", they carry a very high-speed signal over impedance-controlled lines (typically, twisted pairs).

If you built a splitter, that splitter would need to match the impedance of of two parallel 100 Ω wave impedance waveguides to a single one; that means each downstream port could only receive half the power. That means in the best case (lossless) scenario, your output amplitudes would be a factor of \$\sqrt2\$ lower than the input amplitudes.

The [HDMI spec (p. 43)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305072940/http://www.microprocessor.org/HDMISpecification13a.pdf) is pretty precise on the required signal levels:

> 400 mV ≤ V<sub>swing</sub> ≤ 600 mV

So, for the absolute best case, a maximum strength input signal, you'd have exactly a factor of 1.5 of headroom. You're already wasting 1.41 on the power splitting; that leaves virtually no room for any losses.

So, even if a passive lossless splitter could theoretically work, you're already working at the utmost least corner of your signal strength and hence, signal quality.

Then add that lossless splitters are typically bulky<sup>[citation needed]</sup> or don't achieve great isolation between the output ports, you make the cable look way worse in terms of reflections to the receivers: not only are you introducing multiple new points where you'll inevitably have non-perfect match, meaning more reflections, both receivers will observe the other's effects through the imperfect isolation.

Since HDMI receivers have equalizers that aren't designed for that purpose, this will probably lead to serious signal degradation.

From an economical point of view, good power splitters for four differential signals are probably not really cheaper to build into a signal chain than an active repeater that actually receives the incoming signal and has a separate output driver set for both downstream ports.

Here's a [candidate IC](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/PI3HDX414FCEEX/PI3HDX414FCEEXTR-ND/6237515) that can drive up to four HDMI / DVI signals from a single source.

Comment: Note that on page 45, the minimum differential input voltage at the sink is 150 mV, so a passive splitter CAN work, but you've given up a lot of headroom in terms of cable losses.

Comment: Thanks for you proposal. I'll read this data sheet. It's not a matter of price but a matter of space and consumption. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to split passively. There are other pins like hotplug and display data channel that make it a point to point connection only.

Comment: I know there is an I2C signal inside to tell to the receiver witch resolution is possible or not. But it is not mandatory ?

Comment: That is irrelevant. You have very high frequency digital signals going over the cable. You can't 'just' split that without severely corrupting the signal quality.

Comment: It is true that on a Raspberry type of device, it might be possible to make it ignore DDC and hotplug signals and force a certain resolution always out. I've seen it done on an i.MX processor. But you really need a chip for splitting the TMDS lines.